# Php explode array with specific value

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I really need some help with this code and I'm not that good at PHP.

**Here is the code:**

```
function projectAttr($number){
    global $clerk, $project;

    $projectid = $project['id'];
    $tags = array();
    $cleanUrls= (bool) $clerk->getSetting( "clean_urls", 1 );

    $getTags = $clerk->query_select ( "projects_to_tags", "DISTINCT tag", "WHERE projectid='$projectid' ORDER BY id ASC" );
    while ( $tag= $clerk->query_fetchArray( $getTags ) )
        {
            $tagset = explode('; ', $tag['tag']);
        }

    return html_entity_decode($tagset[$number]);
}
```

The code explodes a string and puts it in a array, that I can get by *`projectAttr(0)`*. But I want to be more specific in what I want to get from the string.

**This is my string:**

```
size='large'; caption='short text about post/project'; bgcolor='black'; color='white';
```

What I want is, if I write **`projectAttr(size)`** it should return the value **`large`** and so forth.

Is that even possible?

Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer specifically to the explode you want. You should modify your `projectAttr` function to look this this:

```
$items = explode('; ', $string);

$attr = array();
foreach($items as $item) {
    list($key, $val) = explode('=', $item);
    $attr[$key] = str_replace(array("'", ""), '',$val);
}
```

Which returns

```
Array (
    [size] => large
    [caption] => short text about post/project
    [bgcolor] => black
    [color] => white
)
```

[**EXAMPLE DEMO**](https://eval.in/170080)

---

So modify your function to look like this:

```
function projectAttr($name) {
    global $clerk, $project;

    $projectid = $project['id'];
    $tags = array();
    $cleanUrls = (bool) $clerk->getSetting("clean_urls", 1);

    $getTags = $clerk->query_select("projects_to_tags", "DISTINCT tag", "WHERE projectid='$projectid' ORDER BY id ASC");
    while ($tag = $clerk->query_fetchArray($getTags)) {
        $items = explode('; ', $string);

        $attr = array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            list($key, $val) = explode('=', $item);
            $attr[$key] = str_replace(array("'", ""), '', $val);
        }
    }

    return html_entity_decode($attr[$name]);
}
```

And that should allow you to call it like this:

```
projectAttr('size');
```

Comment: @user2349357 Perfectly alright, glad it helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function projectAttr($number){
    $str= "size='large'; caption='short text about post/project'; bgcolor='black'; color='white';";
    $r = explode('; ', $str);
    foreach($r as $k=>$v) {
        $attr = explode('=', $v);
        $projectAttr[$attr[0]] = str_replace("'", "", $attr[1]);
    }
    return html_entity_decode($projectAttr[$number]);
}
echo projectAttr('size'); // large
```